# How to use for-loop to print a sequence of numbers x_1 to x_10

Tags: python

I have to write a script that uses a for-loop to print a sequence of numbers, `x_1` to `x_10`, where `x_1 = 2` and the subsequent numbers are computed as `x[i] = 2 · x[i−1]`. Any kind of help would be appreciated.

I have a hard time figuring out how to start. I don't know if it's necessary to make a vector, x, first, and if it is, how the vector should look like.

```
x = np.array([...])
for i in range(10):
    x[i] = ...
```

The expected output should print the sequence: `2 4 16 32 64 128 256 512 1024`.

Comment: You can do`x[i]= 2**(i+1)`?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is to just implement your equation:

```
x = np.zeros(10)
x[0] = 2
for i in range(1, 10):
    x[i] = 2 * x[i-1]
```

However, as @DanielMesejo points out, what you're asking to do is mathematically equivalent to `x[i] = 2 ** (i + 1)` (accounting for 0-based indexing), and since you're already using numpy, this becomes really easy:

```
x = 2 ** (1 + np.arange(10))
```

Answer (score 0):

Imagine initial array as a stack then

```
stack=[2]
for i in range(9):
    stack.append(2 * stack[-1])
```